# WPF ComboBox: click outside of popup keep popup open

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

I'm using WPF ComboBox. When popup is opened and user clicks somewhere outside, popup closes. But I would like to leave popup opened and bypass standard behavior of the ComboBox in this case. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891680/wpf-combobox-click-outside-of-popup-suppress-mouse-click?noredirect=1&lq=1) a solution. It is suitable for bypass the standard behavior of ComboBox, but the popup still closes. If I trying to set in this time ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen=true, my application crashes with error "Cannot reopen a popup in the closed event handler".

Have you any ideas how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to set this behaviour to `ComboBox`. You can try to do that with `ListBox` though: just set `ListBox.Height = 20` and expand it on `ListBox.SelectionChanged()`.

And if for some reason you need `ListBox` to look exactly like `ComboBox` - you could use control templates.

Comment: to @pec orange: Thank for comment. I already thought about it, too. But so far I'm trying with ComboBox

Comment: to @pec orange: I now tried with ListBox. Unfortunately, this is not the behavior that I need.