# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn DropdownClosed events

Tags: wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am quite new to the WPF....I ran into this issue where it says "The dropdownclosed is not a routedevent".  here is my code:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="Fleet_Combo" Header="Fleet" Width = "30*" ItemsSource="{Binding acTypeFleet}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Fleet,Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="FleetComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
                            <EventSetter Event="DropDownClosed" Handler="ComboBox_DropDownClosed"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>                        
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: related: [How to get a combobox to appropriately set focus directly after the popup closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710013/how-to-get-a-combobox-to-appropriately-set-focus-directly-after-the-popup-closes)

Comment: thank you. if you post it I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says:  `DropDownClosed` isn't a RoutedEvent, so you can't create a style for ComboBoxes and have them all inherit the event via an EventSetter.

A workaround to invoke the event is to use an event that **is** a RoutedEvent, and hook into that appropriately.  A suitable candidate is `Loaded`.  Follow [Alain's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710013/how-to-get-a-combobox-to-appropriately-set-focus-directly-after-the-popup-closes) to get the Loaded event:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxCellStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
  <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="ComboBox_Loaded" />
</Style>
```

From the loaded event, you can get to the DropDownClosed event

```
private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ((ComboBox)sender).DropDownClosed -= ComboBox_OnDropDownClosed;
  ((ComboBox)sender).DropDownClosed += new 
     System.EventHandler(ComboBox_OnDropDownClosed);
}
```

and from there call the appropriate handler:

```
void ComboBox_OnDropDownClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  ...
}
```